# C secp256k1: creating bindings in another language with FFI

Tags: secp256k1

I am attempting to create bindings from the C library `libsecp256k1` into Scheme (the `guile` implementation) but I am guessing my question applies to other target languages. Say I want to export the function `secp256k1_context_create`: this function expects an `int` as an argument which can be one of the macros `SECP256K1_CONTEXT_VERIFY`, `SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN` or `SECP256K1_CONTEXT_NONE`. Now these macros are part of the C API, but as far I can tell there is no way to access their values from the shared library:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib
$ nm libsecp256k1.so
... (no names relating to flag values)
```

So it seems I need to define my own values for the flags in the target language:

```
(define %context-verify 257)
(define %context-sign 513)
(define %context-none 1)
```

However, in doing so, I am hard-coding implementation details, which means my target language library could break despite the C API being stable (actually I am not sure whether this constitute an API change if existing object code needs to be recompiled, ABI change?). Could anyone let me know whether I have missed anything, or whether there is a better approach to this problem?